# PHP cannot delete file contents

Tags: php

Can someone explain to me why I cannot delete the images that I was able to successfully import in the first half of the function

```
function delete_files($target) {
    foreach(glob($target.'*.*') as $v){
        unlink($v);
    }
}

function importImagesforSlideShow()
{
    $array = $_REQUEST["data"];
    $slidePath = '../../images/carousel-slides/';
    $url = $array[0];
    $images = $array[1];
    $imageExtQualifier = $array[2];

    if (!file_exists($slidePath)) {
        mkdir($slidePath, 0777, true);
    }

    foreach ($images as $imageName) {
        $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'ignore_errors' => true,
                'header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"
            )
        ));

        $urlLoc = $url . $imageName . $imageExtQualifier;
        $img = $imageName . '.jpg';
        file_put_contents($slidePath . $img, file_get_contents($urlLoc, FALSE, $context));
    }

    // not working
    delete_files(__DIR__ . $slidePath); 


    echo json_encode($images);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Salty: I think you are on to something. This does nto look right

G:\PleskVhosts\abc.com\xyz.com\scripts\php../../images/carousel-slides/

it should be something like:

G:\PleskVhosts\abc.com\xyz.com\images/carousel-slides/

How to fix?

Comment: `/` is missing in $urlloc may it would be `$urlLoc = $url . "/".$imageName . "/". $imageExtQualifier;`

Comment: add ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL ); at the begging to see all errors and warnings, it may hint you the problem

Comment: $urlloc is part of the save images, that's working. It is the call " delete_files(__DIR__ . $slidePath); " that is not working.

Comment: echo `__DIR__ . $slidePath` and check your path

Comment: @pavlovich, I am getting no errors in my callback, it just is not deleting the contents.

Comment: @salty: G:\PleskVhosts\abc.com\xyz.com\scripts\php../../images/carousel-slides/" NO clue what that means. (I changed the 2 domain names)

Comment: check permission of folder !!

Comment: I made sure the folder has write and modify permissions, but I think the __Dir__ is the problem. See above.

Comment: Just use `__DIR__ . "images/carousel-slides/"`